# Create a rolling date list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date

I want to create a rolling list of dates in Excel like so:

```
Day     Date
Day 1   01-Jul-19
Day 1   02-Jul-19
Day 1   03-Jul-19
Day 1   04-Jul-19
Day 1   05-Jul-19
Day 1   06-Jul-19
Day 1   07-Jul-19
Day 2   02-Jul-19
Day 2   03-Jul-19
Day 2   04-Jul-19
Day 2   05-Jul-19
Day 2   06-Jul-19
Day 2   07-Jul-19
Day 2   08-Jul-19
Day 3   03-Jul-19
Day 3   04-Jul-19
Day 3   05-Jul-19
Day 3   06-Jul-19
Day 3   07-Jul-19
Day 3   08-Jul-19
Day 3   09-Jul-19
Day 4   04-Jul-19
  .         .
  .         .
  .         .
```

So essentially what's happening is that the 7-day range moves forward by one day each time, from a specific start date (in the example above, 01-07-19) until it reaches an end date. **Is there an automated way of doing this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ashvin10 you can do this in vba, but you can also accomplish this with 2 formulas without using vba at all, here's how:

for illustration purposes we'll just assume you are starting with `07/01/2019` on the first row and your information will be displayed in columns `A` and `B`.

1. in `A1` enter the string `Day 1`
2. in `B1` enter your starting date, like `07/01/2019`
3. in `A2` enter this formula: `="Day " & IF(MOD(ROW(A2),7)<>0, MID(A2,5,(LEN(A2)-4)), MID(A2,5,(LEN(A2)-4))+1)`
4. in `B2` enter this formula: `=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,OFFSET(B2,-7,0)+1)`
5. highlight cells `A2` and `B2`
6. click on the cross that becomes available on the bottom right hand corner of cell `B2`
7. drag down the formula till you hit the end date you desire
8. the cells are populated with the values you requested in the format you requested

[image: Here's a gif showing the whole process from start to finish.]

If you absolutely have to have it done using vba please let me know and I can show you how to do it that way as well, but this way is much easier.

EDIT: @ashvin10 I'm so sorry, the original formula I instructed you to put into `A2` only works for `Day 1` through `Day 9`, if you go into days past 9 it won't display correctly. I've fixed the formula that should be pasted into `A2` so now it will work no matter how many days you go down. I'm so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ashvin10 one of my formulas was wrong, I've corrected it in my answer, please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this can also be done in Python.

```
import datetime

start_date = '01-07-2019'
end_date = '31-01-2020'
output_file_name = 'rolling dates'
output_file_extension = '.CSV'
delimiter = '\t'

with open((output_file_name + output_file_extension.lower()), 'w+') as file:
    header = "Day" + delimiter + "Date" + '\n'
    file.write(header)

    start_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
    end_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
    number_of_days = abs((end_date_object - start_date_object).days)
    next_day = start_date_object

    for i in range(1, number_of_days + 2):
        for j in range(7):
            file.write(("Day {0}" + delimiter + next_day.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') + '\n').format(i))
            next_day += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        start_date_object += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        next_day = start_date_object
```

After running the code above, I simply created a blank Excel file and then imported the data from the CSV file output by this code.

This is arguably more complicated than @gharbad-the-weak's answer but thought I'd include this anyway.

Comment: this is a good adaptation of the principle of my answer. upvoted.